# Move export to another file while changing all files that import it

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

At least on Typescript, it's possible to select a code like

```
export const MyVar = 3;
```

And with Right Click > Refactor, we can move it to a new file, and all the files that had it imported from file A (where it was), will now import it from the new file B (where it now is).

However, I already have the file that I want to move this export, I don't want to create a new one. I want to move the export to an existing file and automatically update all files that import it.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few days ago. I moved a component from one library to another, so I had to updates dozens of imports.
I'm too lazy to do that a second time, so I created something that should helps:

Check the [@itlabs/ts-import-move](https://github.com/swiss-itlabs/ts-utils/blob/main/packages/ts-import-move/README.md)